# What is the different between ClassMapAutoLoader and onBootstrap?

Tags: zend-framework2

What is the difference between `ClassMapAutoLoader` and `onBootstrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Class Map Autoloader

A web application consists of many PHP classes, and each class typically resides in a separate file. This introduces the need of *including* the files.

As your application grows in size, it may be difficult to include
each needed file. Zend Framework 2 itself consists of hundreds of files,
and it can be very difficult to load the entire library and all its 
dependencies this way. Moreover, when executing the resulting code, PHP interpreter will 
take CPU time to process each included file, even if you don't create an 
instance of its class.

To fix this problem, in PHP 5.1, the class autoloading feature has been introduced.
The PHP function `spl_autoload_register()` allows you to register 
an *autoloader* function. For complex web sites, you even can create
several autoloader functions, which are chained in a stack.

During script execution, if PHP interpreter encounters a class name 
which has not been defined yet, it calls all the registered autoloader functions
in turn, until either the autoloader function includes the class or "not found" error is
raised. This allows for "lazy" loading, when PHP interpreter processes the class
definition only at the moment of class invocation, when it is really needed.

To give you an idea of how an autoloader function looks like, below we provide a
simplified implementation of an autoloader function:

```
<?php
// Autoloader function.
function autoloadFunc($className) {

  // Class map static array.
  static $classMap = array(
    'Zend\\Mvc\\Application' => '/path/to/zend/dir/Zend/Mvc/Application.php',
    'Application\\Module' => '/path/to/app/dir/Application/Module.php',
    //...
  );

  // Check if such a class name presents in the class map.
  if(isset(static::$classMap[$className])) {
    $fileName = static::$classMap[$className];

    // Check if file exists and is readable.
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
      // Include the file.
      require $filename;
    }
  }
}

// Register our autoloader function.
spl_autoload_register("autoloadFunc");
```

In the above example, we define the `autoloadFunc()` autoloader function, 
which we will further refer to as the *class map* autoloader.

The class map autoloader uses the class map for mapping between class name and 
absolute path to PHP file containing that class. The class map is just a usual PHP
array containing keys and values. To determine the file path by class name, the 
class map autoloader just needs to fetch the value from the class map array.
It is obvious, that the class map autoloader works very fast. However, the disadvantage 
of it is that you have to maintain the class map and update it each time you add a new 
class to your program.

### onBootstrap

On every HTTP request, the `Zend\Mvc\Application` 
object is created. The application's "life" consists of several stages.

Zend Framework 2 uses the concept of *event*. One class can *trigger* an event,
and other classes may *listen* to events. Technically, triggering an event means just calling another class' "callback" method. The event management is implemented inside of 
the `Zend\Mvc\EventManager` component.

Each application life stage is initiated by the application by triggering an event. Other
classes (either belonging to Zend Framework or specific to your application) may listen 
to events and react accordingly.

Below, the four main events (life stages) are presented:

**Bootstrap**. When this event is triggered by the application, a module has a chance to
register itself as a listener of further application events in its `onBootstrap()` 
callback method.

**Route**. When this event is triggered, the request's URL is analyzed using a *router* class (typically, with 
`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack` class. If an exact match between the URL and a route
is found, the request is passed to the site-specific controller class assigned to the route.

**Dispatch**. The controller class "dispatches" the request using the corresponding action method 
and produces the data that can be displayed on the web page.

**Render**. On this event, the data produced by the controller's action method are passed for rendering to 
`Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` class. The renderer class uses a 
*view template* file for producing an HTML page.

For a beginner to better understand the above mentioned concepts, I would recommend the [Zend Framework 2.0 by Example: Beginner’s Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-2-0-by-example-beginners-guide/book) book or the [Using Zend Framework 2](http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-2-0-by-example-beginners-guide/book) e-book. You may choose the book on your own.

Comment: You might want to mention that you wrote the e-book you're recommending, as per the section on self-promotion: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Yes, you are right. I probably should give the list of books instead, so he will be able to choose himself.